# Unknown ceiling/roof beam installed in old renovation

Tags: ceiling, roof, structural, load-bearing, beam

This house has a shallow (approx ~15°) gable roof, and raked interior ceilings to match.

In past renovations, a large horizontal beam was installed which runs the entire length of the house, on the underside of the peak of the roof/ceiling (new/old photos below). It has been cleanly plastered over to match the ceiling.

[image]

Can anyone suggest why this may have been done? I'm unsure of the purpose of the beam, and I'm left wondering if it was installed to address a structural issue, or to increase the load bearing capacity of the roof, or whether it was installed as a step towards creating horizontal ceiling spaces... or something else.

Comment: What makes you think it "serves no apparent purpose?" Big beams tend to keep roofs from falling down, and that's purpose enough for them...

Comment: This seems like something you need somebody there to tell you.  From the placement, not something I would be willing to remove, without a expert to tell me.  Can be anything from simple(odd) decoration to structural support.  Your general location might give extra ideas.

Comment: That’s a very large beam. Were there other additions/ remodels completed besides adding the beam, installing new perimeter ceiling trim, etc. ?

Comment: The location of the house doesn't experience snow, and yes, other additions were the cornice strips.

Comment: @LeeSam that beam is slighly smaller than the one holding my roof up. And it is no addition - it is a structural part since day 1.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious major renovation with the enclosure around the fireplace, etc. Perhaps a major repair on the roof structure too.  (Is the roofing new too.)

Comment: The roofing isn't new, but it was entirely removed to add new insulation around the time the renovation to install the beam was done.

Comment: Maybe something was found when the roof work was being done.